# Error - Runtime error 13. How do I get the row count to add up?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on this code on my own for the past week and seem to run into a new issue everyday. Today's issue is occurring when I try to get a row count for a worksheet so it can pull down formulas on another worksheet.

I've used

```
lrSell = Cells(Rows.Count, TradeDateSell).End(xlUp).Row
'Run time error 13
'and
Set lrSell = Cells(Rows.Count, TradeDateSell).End(xlUp).Row
'Compile error: Object required
```

Code is as follows

```
Dim Transactions As Workbook
Dim Macro As Workbook
'Sales
Dim SellData As Worksheet
Dim MonthlySales As Worksheet
Dim TradeDateSell As Range
Dim NoSales As Range
'Buys
Dim BuyData As Worksheet
Dim MonthlyBuys As Worksheet
Dim TradeDateBuy As Range
Dim NoBuys As Range
'Other info
Dim Others As Worksheet
Dim Summary As Worksheet
Dim PrvDay As Date
Dim Workdates As Worksheet
Dim BuysPaste As Worksheet
Dim MyCell As Range

'Definitions
Set Transactions = ActiveWorkbook
Set Macro = ThisWorkbook
Set BuysPaste = Macro.Sheets("Buys")
Set Workdates = Macro.Sheets("Dates")
PrvDay = (Workdates.Range("B2").Value)
Set Others = Transactions.Sheets("others")
Set Summary = Transactions.Sheets("Summary")

'Sell Def
Set SellData = Transactions.Sheets("SellData")
Set MonthlySales = Transactions.Sheets("Monthly Sales")
Set NoSales = Others.Range("A37:CD37")
'Buy Def
Set BuyData = Transactions.Sheets("BuyData")
Set MonthlyBuys = Transactions.Sheets("Monthly Buys")
Set NoBuys = Others.Range("A36:CD36")

'Find the column that will be searched
SellData.Activate
Set TradeDateSell = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Trade Date", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

'Find the column that will be searched
BuyData.Activate
Set TradeDateBuy = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Trade Date", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

'Check if Sales were made
SellData.Activate
Dim lrSell As Long
lrSell = Cells(Rows.Count, TradeDateSell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

For Each Cell In Range(TradeDateSell.Column & lrSell)
    If Cell.Value = PrvDay Then
    Else
        NoSales.Copy Destination:=SellData.Rows(TradeDateSell.Offset(1, -7))
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'Offset allows it to paste in the A column
lrSell = Cells(Rows.Count, TradeDateSell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
'Counting Rows again after adjustments were made

'Check if Buys were made
BuyData.Activate
Dim lrBuy As Long
lrBuy = Cells(Rows.Count, TradeDateBuy.Column).End(xlUp).Row

For Each Cell In Range(TradeDateBuy.Column & lrBuy).Cells
    If Cell.Value = PrvDay Then
    Else
        NoBuys.Copy Destination:=BuyData.Rows(TradeDateBuy.Offset(1, -10))
        Exit For
    End If
Next
'Offset allows it to paste in the A column
lrBuy = Cells(Rows.Count, TradeDateBuy.Column).End(xlUp).Row
'Counting Rows again after adjustments were made

'Drag down all columns in Monthly tabs to the same number rows in the data tabs
MonthlyBuys.Range("A2:CN2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:CN" & lrBuy)
MonthlySells.Range("A2:CG2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:CG" & lrSell)

'Refresh All PivotTables
Summary.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'Filter for PRVDay in the monthly buys tab and copy all and paste into BuysPaste worksheet in the Macro workbook
'Clear filter once complete

MsgBox "Please confirm if all totals are correct before running the Equitable Macro", vbOKOnly, "Please use EquitableMacro for the next steps"
```

If you notice anything else is off or need information, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: You are trying to use `TradeDateSell` before is even declared... Also you are using `lrSell` before declaring it, you declare it as a `Long` variable and later on you try to `Set lrSell`.... Only objects need `Set` to be set. You are also using `TradeDateSell` as column index when is a range, you should use `TradeDateSell.Column`

Comment: 1. you need to append the parent sheet to all ranges to ensure vba knows which cell you want: `worksheets("Sheet1").Cells...` 2 what is the value of `TradeDateSell` when it errors?

Comment: NVM, number 2 above.  You want `TradeDateSell.Column` to return the column number to the `Cells()`

Comment: and `For Each MyCell In Range(TradeDateSell & lrSell)` is not doing what you think it should.  It would return an error because it is the joining of the value of the data in `TradedateSell` or `Trade Date` and a number provided by `lrSell` and there is no range with that address.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Setting it as column has worked. Scott, you're correct in that it won't search the column for that date. How would I be able to adjust the code to have it search that column for a specific date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even know if this code will work because is way too messed up, but at least gave you a few tips:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    'you are trying to use lrSell it before you even declare the variable, same goes with TradeDateSell but also you need its .Column property
    'lrSell = Cells(Rows.Count, TradeDateSell).End(xlUp).Row
    'Run time error 13
    'and
    'You can't use Set for a Long variable, is only for Object variables such as Workbooks, Worksheets, Dictionaries, objects...
    'Set lrSell = Cells(Rows.Count, TradeDateSell).End(xlUp).Row
    'Compile error: Object required

    Dim TradeDateSell As Range
    Dim TradeDateBuy As Range

    'Is highly recomendable to qualify the whole range you are talking about
    'If you are working on the same sheet for all this code you can do by using a dot before any Range or Cell like
    ' .Range() or .Cells() just by using the With Block below
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
        Set TradeDateSell = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Trade Date", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
            , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'see how I've added the dots on .RAnge("A1") and .Rows("1:1")
        Set TradeDateBuy = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Trade Date", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
            , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Dim lrSell As Long

        'like we stated before a long variable doesn't need Set to be set, also you need the column from TradeDateSell
        lrSell = Cells(Rows.Count, TradeDateSell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        'to build a range you need the first cell and the last one, being the first in this case TradeDateSell
        'and the last Cells(lrSell, TradeDateSell.Column)
        Dim PrvDay As String 'you didn't declare PrvDay neither give it value to check
        Dim NoSales As Range 'you didn't declare NoSales nor set it
        Dim SellData As Range 'you didn't declare SellData nor set it

        Set NoSales = .Range("??") 'set your variable
        Set SellData = .Range("??") 'set your variable
        PrvDay = "?" 'give PrvDay a value

        For Each MyCell In .Range(TradeDateSell, .Cells(lrSell, TradeDateSell.Column))
            If MyCell.Value = PrvDay Then
            Else
                NoSales.Copy Destination:=SellData.Rows(TradeDateSell.Offset(1, -7).Row) 'you need the .Row property for the range
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'Offset allows it to paste in the A column

        lrSell = .Cells(Rows.Count, TradeDateSell).End(xlUp).Row '
        'Counting Rows again after adjustments were made

        Dim lrBuy As Long
        lrBuy = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TradeDateBuy.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim NoBuys As Range
        Dim BuyData As Range

        Set NoBuys = .Range("??")
        Set BuyData = .Range("??")

        For Each MyCell In .Range(TradeDateSell, .Cells(lrSell, lrBuy.Column))
            If MyCell.Value = PrvDay Then
            Else
                NoBuys.Copy Destination:=BuyData.Rows(TradeDateBuy.Offset(1, -10).Row)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'Offset allows it to paste in the A column
        lrBuy = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TradeDateBuy).End(xlUp).Row
        'Counting Rows again after adjustments were made

        Dim MonthlyBuys As Range
        Dim MonthlySells As Range

        Set MonthlyBuys = .Range("??")
        Set MonthlySells = .Range("??")

        'Drag down all columns in Monthly tabs to the same number rows in the data tabs
        MonthlyBuys.Range("A2:CN2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2:CN" & lrBuy)
        MonthlySells.Range("A2:CG2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2:CG" & lrSell)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: lmao. I'm hopeless.. I'll post up the all the code and we can start from there

Comment: This didn't solve the problem completely but since you already helped me solve the the issue addressed in the question I'm going to mark this as complete. Since I'm still new I can't give you a +1 yet

Comment: Your code now is insanely large and messy, try to modify it following the suggestions I made. I also recommend you to declare your variables just before you use them, so you always know where to find the type of variable you are working on. What is the error now?

Comment: For Each MyCell In .Range(TradeDateSell, .Cells(lrSell, TradeDateSell.Column))

"Invalid or unqualified reference"

Comment: that means most likely `TradeDateSell = Nothing`